# Does spawning new processes use all CPU cores in elixir

Tags: elixir

Suppose, I'm on a 4-core CPU machine.

If I run the following in my elixir VM:

```
 1..4 |> Enum.map fn(x) -> spawn(computationally_heavy_process) end
```

Does this use all 4 cores of my machine. One of each of the computationally heavy processes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. By default, Erlang starts one scheduler (OS thread) for each CPU, and attempts to distribute load evenly across the schedulers. However, it is not guaranteed that the four processes end up being processed in four different CPUs, because there are usually much more things happening in parallel. If you want to know how many schedulers Erlang has started, just fire up `iex` (or `erl`, for that matter).

```
~$ iex
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]
...
```

For example, my computer has a CPU with 8 cores. In the first line of the output, you can see the current configuration. From the part `[smp:8:8]`, you can see that [SMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing) is configured with 8 schedulers, 8 of which are online. The number of schedulers/threads can be overridden with [the `+S` flag](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#+S).

> **+S Schedulers:SchedulerOnline**
>
> Sets the number of scheduler threads to create and scheduler threads
>   to set online when SMP support has been enabled. The maximum for both
>   values is 1024. If the Erlang runtime system is able to determine the
>   amount of logical processors configured and logical processors
>   available, Schedulers will default to logical processors configured,
>   and SchedulersOnline will default to logical processors available;
>   otherwise, the default values will be 1. [...]

The number of schedulers online can also be changed at runtime via [`:erlang.system_flag(:schedulers_online, n)`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_flag_schedulers_online). However, I would advise against changing any of the defaults unless you run into a specific problem.

Comment: Erlang and OTP in Action covers the basics of this really well in one of the first chapters. http://www.amazon.com/Erlang-OTP-Action-Martin-Logan/dp/1933988789

Comment: Edited my answer to provide more detail on how to introspect the current scheduler configuration and links to Erlang documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Well the elixir VM is simply the Erlang VM - which schedules how spawned processes get assigned to machine CPU.  You don't have direct control AFAIK.  However you can see how the 4 schedulers are being occupied within the VM by using the visualisation of the Charts by issuing `:observer.start()` before you run your own code. I've found it seems to do a pretty reasonable job.  For a reality check you can also run `top` on a linux OS.  This can show how much of each cpu is being actually used - try pressing 1 in top from a different console on the same machine.